# Flood Elevation Setback

Tags: arcgis-desktop, flood

I have a floodplain layer with elevations assigned to it. Per scope of the project, I need to create a safety setback. The flood elevation is raised by 2 ft. and when the raised point extended horizontally to the ground becomes the setback. How do I create this setback/buffer?

Comment: can you define 'setback' nearest point to dry land from the edge of the flood plain?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  Can you use the **edit** button beneath your question to do the above but also to include the version of ArcGIS for Desktop that you are using, please?

Answer (score 8):

You didn't specify a software requirement for your solution (although there is an ArcGIS tag on the question) so I've provided a method below based on the free and open-source GIS [Whitebox Geospatial Analysis Tools](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/download.shtml), for which I am a developer.

Whitebox GAT has a tool called **Elevation Above Stream** (see image below):

[image]

For a given DEM and rasterized stream network...

[image]

...the tool will calculate the elevation difference between each location and its nearest downslope stream cell:

[image]

You can then threshold using the **Raster Calculator**, **Reclass** tool, **Less Than** tool, or **Conditional Evaluation** tool. In this example I've simply pulled out each cell in the *elevation above stream* raster with a value less than 2 ft and vectorized the resulting polygons:

[image]

There are your setbacks! I should also note that while I used a stream network as the target in this example, you could easily replace the required input streams file to the tool with a rasterized version of a floodplain polygon. It would work equally well, but would redefine the output as *elevation above the floodplain*. In fact, this is nearly the exact application that inspired me to develop this tool in the first place. Good luck and let me know if you need any further details.

Comment: +1.  Great answer.  I wouldn't delete your answer even if an Arc solution is required.  This may be useful to other users who are trying to do the same thing.  And WhiteboxGAT is a great program.

Comment: @Fezter Thanks for the feedback. It's well appreciated.