# Creating flood area based on connected pixels of DEM in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, dem, flood

I am trying to show the area of flooding that occurs when bodies of water increase by different increments, like 0.5, 1, 1.5 meters, etc.. for all of Tanzania. I have a DEM with all of the bodies of water clipped out and the inverse -the dem of just the bodies of water. My thought is to locate all of the connected pixels to the body of water locations above 0.5, 1, and 1.5 meters (above the particular water source).

I tried experimenting with the cost distance tool in ArcGIS but am not sure if it is the correct tool for the job.

I prefer to use python and/or ArcGIS.

Is there a good way to show what areas would be flooded nearby bodies of water? Is the approach I am considering valid?

[image]

Comment: What were the precise steps involved in your "experimenting with the cost distance tool in ArcGIS"?  What was unsatisfactory about the result?

Comment: @PolyGeo I kept receiving a raster with zero values. I tried putting the source raster as the DEM of just the water bodies and the cost raster as the DEM of non water bodies. I was not sure if I did it correctly.

Comment: Please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it with any requested information.

Comment: I would recommend a different  approach using the DEM and contours.

Comment: @whyzar mind elaborating or linking to proposed method if you have time?

Comment: I described my approach in comments to this question http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/224588/indicating-height-spectrum-1-m-above-and-below-inclined-plane-that-cuts-through#comment346697_224588

Comment: It sounds like you might be looking for the solution described at http://www.quantdec.com/SYSEN597/studies/flood/index.htm.  It uses a precursor of ArcGIS, whose syntax has changed in the 15 years since that solution was posted, but exactly the same capabilities are still available in ArcGIS+Spatial Analyst.

Comment: @whuber This is actually why I thought to use the cost distance tool. Unfortunately I think this methodology is more applicable towards single bodies of water. The various streams and lakes will have different elevations, so I am not sure if it would be possible to use this methodology at a country wide scale, unless I misunderstood it.

Comment: I believe you would have to do it one stream at a time.  The methodology is only a crude approximation to modeling the flood of a nearly level river reach, anyway.  For river with appreciable gradient, it's hard to find an accurate substitute for a hydrological model.

Answer (score 1):

Although I have done a lot with rivers I would not consider myself a flood modeller and I suspect I have over simplified my answer.

There is the [Expand](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/expand.htm) tool that you could use to expand out the expansion of a lake 1 pixel at a time which you could then test to see if is below 1m or not. If it is, you keep it and then feed back the expanded lake? So this solution would involve a lot of looping which you would do in modelbuilder or python.

There is almost certainly a tool out there that does this but I guess it is finding the right search term, try flood modelling or flood routing?

For example the ever awesome [Whitebox GAT](http://www.uoguelph.ca/~hydrogeo/Whitebox/index.html) gis system (which amazingly is free) has a tool call flood order...

Comment: Thanks for the Whitebox GAT mention. I hadn't heard of that before. It ended up having a tool called "Elevation above stream" that I found from this page: "http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126308/flood-elevation-setback".

Comment: @WhiteboxDev to the rescue! :)

Answer (score 1):

A partial answer to my question was found here: [Flood Elevation Setback](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126308/flood-elevation-setback). Partial due to preferring an arc based solution. I was able to create the following, using a flow accumulation grid for streams and a flow direction grid, all derived from a DEM. May play around with parameters a bit.  [image]